# MantisBT: How to switch off inserting [^] into notes

Tags: mantis

When I add a XML document into a Mantis note, e.g. an XML fragment:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

Mantis considers the XML namespace declaration as a hyperlink and adds a "[^]" string behind:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> [^]
```

If the user copy/pastes the XML from Mantis it is not valid due to these unwanted strings.

Is there any way how to switch this feature off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using a legacy version of Mantis; you can switch off URL processing by changing the corresponding setting in the *MantisCoreFormatting* plugin: go to *Manage > Manage Plugins* then click on *MantisBT Formatting* and set *URL Processing* to Off).

Note that recent versions of MantisBT no longer insert the `[^]`.